# ClassCastException reason

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf

I am getting `ClassCastException`. These two classes are from different jars but 
JettyContinuationProviderFactory  is implementing ContinuationProviderFactory class.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory to org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory to org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3186) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeanOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:326) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.getBeanOfType(SpringBeanLocator.java:138) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.getExtension(CXFBusImpl.java:107) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.initConfig(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:519) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.<init>(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:149) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.<init>(ServletDestination.java:52) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestinationFactory.createDestination(ServletDestinationFactory.java:33) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:305) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getDestination(SoapTransportFactory.java:142) [cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:83) [cxf-api-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:62) [cxf-api-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:170) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    ... 32 more

17:02:35,992 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/cisBusiness]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fulFillment': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory to org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory to org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483) [spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.continuations.JettyContinuationProviderFactory to org.apache.cxf.transport.http.ContinuationProviderFactory
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3186) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeanOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:326) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBeanLocator.getBeanOfType(SpringBeanLocator.java:138) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl.getExtension(CXFBusImpl.java:107) [cxf-rt-core-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.initConfig(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:519) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.<init>(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:149) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.<init>(ServletDestination.java:52) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestinationFactory.createDestination(ServletDestinationFactory.java:33) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPTransportFactory.getDestination(HTTPTransportFactory.java:305) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapTransportFactory.getDestination(SoapTransportFactory.java:142) [cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.initDestination(ServerImpl.java:83) [cxf-api-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:62) [cxf-api-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:170) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.14.jar:2.7.14]
    ... 32 more
```

I have made demo of soap web service in Tomcat that was working fine. But These errors are generating in case of JBOSS EAP 6. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: can you share that piece of code ?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be a classloading issue, whereby you probably have 2x different jars on the classpath which both contain `ContinuationProviderFactory.class`.

Different parts of the code may now be using different versions of that interface, so your `JettyContinuationProviderFactory` is now implementing one version, but the method you are passing your `JettyContinuationProviderFactory` instance to is expecting the other interface.

This creates a type conflict that cannot be resolved by a cast, hence this exception. As silly as that may seem, it makes perfect sense from a JVM classloading perspective.

The reason why it works on Tomcat is that your classpath there might just happen to be cleaner.
The solution is to investigate which jars on the classpath are providing `ContinuationProviderFactory` and eliminate the duplicate.